# Проблема с хэшированием в шахматной программе

Tags: алгоритм

Я использую обычный альфа бета алгоритм. 
При использовании статической оценки позиции и хэширование, производительность резко увеличивается.
Но если использовать quiescence search, то скорость резко падет. У меня есть догадки, что идет отсечение по beta в quiescence search, но как именно реализовать, я не знаю

```
int alpha_beta(int alpha, int beta, int depth, int current_player) {
int score;
current_hash ^= zobrist_key_move;

HASH_TABLE *hash_ptr;
hash_ptr = &hash_table[current_hash % (MAX_HASH_TABLE_SIZE)];
if (hash_ptr->deep >= depth && hash_ptr->key == current_hash) {
    // При динамической оценки позиции, производительность резко падает
    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }

    // К моему удивлению, этот вариант резко повышает производительность
//  if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT && (hash_ptr->score >= beta) ) {
//  return hash_ptr->score;
//  }

   // С этими проверками все хорошо, они увеличивают скорость
    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_ALPHA && hash_ptr->score <= alpha) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }

    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_BETA && hash_ptr->score >= beta) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }
}
if (depth <= 0) {
    count_nodes++;
    score = quiesce(alpha, beta, current_player, DEPTH - 1);
    hash_to_table(current_hash, score, depth, HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT);

    return score;
}

generate_moves(depth, current_player);
sort_move(depth);

if (moves[depth][0].MoveType == MOVE_TYPE_EMPTY) {
    if (king_is_checked(WHITE) || king_is_checked(BLACK)) {
        return -CHECKMATE - depth;
    }
    return 0;
}

int flag = HASH_TABLE_TYPE_ALPHA;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (moves[depth][i].MoveType != MOVE_TYPE_EMPTY) {

        make_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        score = -alpha_beta(-beta, -alpha, depth - 1, !current_player);
        rollback_move(moves[depth][i], depth);

        if (score >= beta) {
            hash_to_table(current_hash, beta, depth, HASH_TABLE_TYPE_BETA);
            return beta;
        }
        if (score > alpha) {
            flag = HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT;
            alpha = score;
            if (depth == max_current_deep) {
                out_move[0] = moves[depth][i];
            }
        }
    }
}

hash_to_table(current_hash, alpha, depth, flag);
return alpha;
}

int quiesce(int alpha, int beta, int current_player, int depth) {
// if static evaluate, uncomment
//return evaluate(current_player);

count_nodes++;
int stand_pat = evaluate(current_player);

if (stand_pat >= beta) {
    return beta;
}
if (alpha < stand_pat) {
    alpha = stand_pat;
}

generate_moves(depth, current_player);
sort_move(depth);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (moves[depth][i].MoveType == MOVE_TYPE_EAT) {
        make_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        int score = -quiesce(-beta, -alpha, !current_player, depth - 1);
        rollback_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        if (score >= beta) {
            return beta;
        }

        if (score > alpha) {
            alpha = score;
        }
    }
}
return alpha;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.

Дело в том, что при вызове quiescence search мы не имеем право использовать exact таблицу, так там там идут отсечения по альфе и бете.

Вот код примера, который правильно работает:

```
int alpha_beta(int alpha, int beta, int depth, int current_player) {
int score;
current_hash ^= zobrist_key_move;

HASH_TABLE *hash_ptr;
hash_ptr = &hash_table[current_hash % (MAX_HASH_TABLE_SIZE)];
if (hash_ptr->deep >= depth && hash_ptr->key == current_hash) {

    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }

    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_ALPHA && hash_ptr->score <= alpha) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }

    if (hash_ptr->type == HASH_TABLE_TYPE_BETA && hash_ptr->score >= beta) {
        return hash_ptr->score;
    }
}
if (depth <= 0) {
    return quiesce(alpha, beta, current_player, DEPTH - 1);
}

generate_moves(depth, current_player);
sort_move(depth);

if (moves[depth][0].MoveType == MOVE_TYPE_EMPTY) {
    if (king_is_checked(WHITE) || king_is_checked(BLACK)) {
        return -CHECKMATE - depth;
    }
    return 0;
}

int flag = HASH_TABLE_TYPE_ALPHA;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (moves[depth][i].MoveType != MOVE_TYPE_EMPTY) {

        make_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        score = -alpha_beta(-beta, -alpha, depth - 1, !current_player);
        rollback_move(moves[depth][i], depth);

        if (score >= beta) {
            hash_to_table(current_hash, beta, depth, HASH_TABLE_TYPE_BETA);
            return beta;
        }
        if (score > alpha) {
            flag = HASH_TABLE_TYPE_EXACT;
            alpha = score;
            if (depth == max_current_deep) {
                out_move[0] = moves[depth][i];
            }
        }
    }
}

hash_to_table(current_hash, alpha, depth, flag);
return alpha;
}

int quiesce(int alpha, int beta, int current_player, int depth) {
// if static evaluate, uncomment
//return evaluate(current_player);

count_nodes++;
int stand_pat = evaluate(current_player);

if (stand_pat >= beta) {
    return beta;
}
if (alpha < stand_pat) {
    alpha = stand_pat;
}

generate_moves(depth, current_player);
sort_move(depth);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (moves[depth][i].MoveType == MOVE_TYPE_EAT) {
        make_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        int score = -quiesce(-beta, -alpha, !current_player, depth - 1);
        rollback_move(moves[depth][i], depth);
        if (score >= beta) {
            return beta;
        }

        if (score > alpha) {
            alpha = score;
        }
    }
}
return alpha;
}
```

Comment: Подробнее можно почитать тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034854/quiescence-search-handling-exact-alpha-beta-flag-for-transposition-table